# windows 8 boot error

Tags: windows-8, boot

Hi I am using Sony Vaio laptop with windows 8 OS, when I power on my laptop blue screen appears and it says your PC needs to be repaired, a required device not connected or cannot be accessed Error code: 0xc000000f. and it says you will need to use the recovery tools on your installation media. if you don't have any installation media(like a disc or USB device) contact your system administrator or PC manufacturer.
and in the bottom it says press enter to try again, press F8 to start up settings, press Esc for UEFI Firmware settings. 
when i pressed F8 there is another blue screen appears saying your PC needs to be repaired, 
the operating system couldnt be loaded because the system registry file is missing or contains errors. and it showed some path windows:/system32/.....
Error code: 0xc000014c.
i don`t have any recovery media.
can any one help please, 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on your information, it sounds like a Virus corrupted your registry, or you hard drive is beginning to fail. You can get a bootable recover USB Thumb Drive, that contains the Windows 8 OS by contacting Sony Support, they might charge you for this. Then you can do the recovery, and troubleshoot weather it was a virus, or your drive is failing.